# Double negative lookbehind in regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am filtering out lines in a SQL script that contain certain person IDs.  For my purposes it's better to be overzealous in my filtering than under, but I'd still like to be a little careful.

For example, if one of the person ids is `123`, and a line contains `[blob_id] = 123`, I don't want to filter that out.  So, I want to find `123` (with word-separators on either side) as long as either it's not preceded by `[<some_id_here>] =` or, `<some_id_here>` = `person_id`.

The regex should match each of these lines:

```
123
[person_id] = 123
blah,blah,123,blah
```

And it should not match each of these lines:

```
foo123bar
[blob_id] = 123
```

I thought this regex would work:

```
(?<!\[(?!person_id)\] = )\b123\b
```

The outer negative look-behind says "the string can't be preceded by `[<some_id_here>] =`".  The inner look-ahead says "this string can match anything but `person_id`.  I would think the double-negation would mean "if this string is preceded by `[<some_id_here>] =`, `<some_id_here>` must only be `person_id`.

Unfortunately, that does not seem to be the case.  It works in all my test cases except `[blob_id] = 123`.

I believe what's happening is, for some reason, because of the double-negation, the outer look-behind matches anything.

Here's my [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/yJ4wI8/1) with my test cases.

Comment: Are you using PCRE as your regex101 link suggests?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  I was testing it on the site before using it in my program, and am having troubles even getting it to work there.

Comment: In other words: what language are you using?

Comment: I will be using C#.  I think I just found an alternative Regex that accomplishes what I want.  `((?<!\] = )|(?<=\[person_id\] = ))\b123\b`

Comment: If you look at my answer you'll see why tagging the language is *really* important with regex questions. I started writing a totally different answer than what I'd write if I knew you're using C# up front. :-)

Comment: This `(?!person_id)\]` will always pass because `p` is _NOT_ `]`. Since it always passes, you can remove it. It now becomes `(?<!\[\] = )`. So, at the boundary position at `123`, the engine looks 5 characters to the left to see if `[] = ` is there. Its never there, so it does `\b123\b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're filtering out whole lines it's easier: if you find anything you don't want in a line, you can throw the line away.

If you're using PCRE you can make use of backtracking verbs to achieve what you want:

```
\bblob_id\b.+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b123\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oM1nP1/2)

If the regex engine encounters `blob_id` on a line, it will match until the end of the line (`.+`) and then fail the match and start over trying at the position where it failed (`(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`). This works because the engine always tries alternatives left-to-right.

---

In C#, you don't have `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`, so you can use this instead:

```
\bblob_id\b.+|(?<id>\b123\b)
```

Check for `match.Groups["id"].Success`. If it's false, throw the match away.

**But the best alternative in C# is...** to use variable-length lookbehinds (a great feature of the C# regex engine):

```
\b123\b(?<!\bblob_id\b.*)
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb123%5cb(%3f%3c!%5cbblob_id%5cb.*)&i=The+regex+should+match+each+of+these+lines%3a%0d%0a123%0d%0a%5bperson_id%5d+%3d+123%0d%0ablah%2cblah%2c123%2cblah%0d%0a%0d%0aAnd+it+should+not+match+each+of+these+lines%3a%0d%0afoo123bar%0d%0a%5bblob_id%5d+%3d+123)

I've put the assertion *after* the match just for optimization, so the engine will actually check the lookbehind only if it already matched `\b123\b` successfully.

---

Looks like I misunderstood the question:

> In your second demo, the only `<some_id_here>` that it filters out is `blob_id`. I need it to filter out any id that isn't `person_id`.

Well, in that case you need to put back those brackets to tell what an ID and what's something else. I suppose I can make use of them since you did exactly that in your question. Then the double negative lookaround makes sense:

```
\b123\b(?<!\[(?!person_id\b)\w+\][^\]\n]*)
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb123%5Cb(%3F%3C!%5C%5B(%3F!person_id%5Cb)%5Cw%2B%5C%5D%5B%5E%5C%5D%5Cn%5D*)&i=The%20regex%20should%20match%20each%20of%20these%20lines%3A%0D%0A123%0D%0A%5Bperson_id%5D%20%3D%20123%0D%0Ablah%2Cblah%2C123%2Cblah%0D%0ADELETE%20FROM%20%5Bdbo%5D.%5Bsecu_login%5D%20WHERE%20%5Bperson_id%5D%20%3D%20123%0D%0A%0D%0AAnd%20it%20should%20not%20match%20each%20of%20these%20lines%3A%0D%0Afoo123bar%0D%0A%5Bblob_id%5D%20%3D%20123)

`[^\]\n]` means *any character except `]` and a newline*, so you only get the closest identifier to the searched value.

Comment: Would this still be performant if the `123` in `\b123\b` were 665 strings joined with `|`?  Or it would it be better to make 665 `Regex` instances and run them?  Or faster to run an ` if (string.Contains(myId) && myRegex.IsMatch(myIdRegex))`? (Or should I just test this?)

Comment: @dfoverdx you should just test this, as with all performance-related questions :-) but you can also try to factor in the IDs, like instead of writing `123|128|236|237|238` you could write `12[38]|23[6-8]`

Comment: In your second demo, the only `<some_id_here>` that it filters out is `blob_id`.  I need it to filter out any id that isn't `person_id`.  Is it easy to do this with your method, or does that make it more complicated?

Comment: @dfoverdx argh I misunderstood your question I see... I've updated the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I found a line that should match and doesn't.  It appears to happen when another `[` is in the string.  `DELETE FROM [dbo].[secu_login] WHERE [person_id] = 123`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `(?!person_id)` doesn't match any characters. What you can do instead is use a negative lookbehind in the negative lookbehind to remove the need to actually consume anything in the negative lookbehind.

```
(?<!(?<!\[person_id)\] = )\b123\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bY7lJ6/1)

Comment: Interesting.  So the issue was that the brackets were on the outside of the inner look-ahead.

Comment: Right, what you were basically saying was: "Match `[]` but only if the closing bracket has not suddenly become `person_id`"

Answer (score 1):

This might give a clearer explanation of what's going on, and
how to add a list of *OK* Id's while excluding other Id's in the
bracket format you've defined.

*edit* - A tip for doing assertions.
Assertions are self contained constructs. They act independently from
one another. Assertions don't know if they are inside other
assertions. The position given to them is the current position
*relative* to the caller, which could be different than the *outter most*
current position.

Lastly, it doesn't matter what the assertion is, inside the assertion,
the expression is *compelled* to match .. that's the primary rule.
The success or failure of that match is logically resolved to the type of
assertion it is, ie. negative/positive result.

`@"(?<!\[(?!(?:person_id|ok_id)\])[^\]]+\]\s*=\s*)\b123\b"`

```
 .*                      # For testing purposes, get whole line before

 (?<!                    # Bracket ID's can't be behind the '123'
      \[                      # Open bracket [
      (?!                     # Exclude ID's that are OK to be here
           (?:
                person_id               # this id is OK
             |  ok_id                   # this id is OK (add more here, etc..)          
           )
           \] 
      )
      [^\]]+                  # 1 or more id chars
      \]                      # Close bracket ]
      \s*                     # Optional whtiespace
      =                       # Equals sign
      \s*                     # Optional whtiespace
 )
 \b 123 \b 

 .*                      # For testing purposes, get whole line after
```

Code snippet:

```
string input = @"
123
[person_id] = 123
blah,blah,123,blah

foo123bar
[blob_id] = 123
";
Regex Rx123 = new Regex(@".*(?<!\[(?!(?:person_id|ok_id)\])[^\]]+\]\s*=\s*)\b123\b.*");
Match _m = Rx123.Match( input );
while (_m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found: {0}", _m.Groups[0].Value);
    _m = _m.NextMatch();
}
```

Output:

```
Found: 123
Found: [person_id] = 123
Found: blah,blah,123,blah
```